# Finding hits based on subgroups (A, B, C) in big data set

Tags: bash, awk, grep, compare, bioinformatics

I have a huge amount of data to analyze.

From this example file I need to know all hits ("samples") that were found either

- only in B,
- only in C,
- in A and C or
- in A and B,

but not the ones that are found

- in B and C or
- in A, B and C.

[edit: to keep it more simple: there should be no co-occurence of B and C]

These letters are found in column $8.

The first two columns together can be used as an identifier for each "sample".

Example: You can see that for “463;88” we find A and C in column $8 which would make “463;88” a hit that I need in a separate output file. "348;64" is found in A, B and C and would therefore be discarded/ignored.

File1.csv

```
463;88;1;193187729;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188065;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188527;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188542;280062;CDC73;IS;C;0.0
348;64;1;155219446;384172;GBAP1;IS;B;0.0
348;64;1;155224629;384172;GBAP1;IS;C;0.0
348;64;1;155224965;384172;GBAP1;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27400461;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27400930;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27401162;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27403518;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27403545;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27404353;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27419156;145220;NRBP1;IS;B;0.0
7;14;20;2894103;92099;PTPRA;IS;B;0.0
7;14;20;2906211;92099;PTPRA;IS;C;0.0
7;14;20;2907301;92099;PTPRA;IS;C;0.0
...
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this, eg with bash, awk, grep...?

It does not need to be very efficient or fast, it just needs to be reliable.

Edit:

I generated a csv table with the columns 1 and 2 of lines that contain <3 different entries in column $8 in several steps.

awk print $1, $2, $8 | sort –n | uniq > file.tmp1

awk print $1, $2 from file.tmp1 | sort –n | unic –c | sed for csv format > file.tmp2

Finally,
awk to print only the identifier columns from file.tmp2 where the count was <3 (= only one or two different letters in column $8 of original file).

File2.csv
6;3;
12;9;
348;40;
463;88;
...

Then, I wanted to use 
fgrep --file=File2.csv File1.csv

but this does not seem to work properly. And it still requires manual analysis as it gives me also false hits.

Comment: so show the desired result for your input example

Comment: If it's in `A and B and C` then it's in `B and C` so you don't need to state and we don't need to think about the `A and B and C` requirement, right? What about `only in A`? You list 6 different combinations for us to consider - I really think you could state your requirements more simply as just 1 "not B and C".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the expected output in your question so it's a guess but is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{ curr = $1 FS $2 }
curr != prev { prt(); prev=curr }
{ lines[++numLines]=$0; seen[$8]++ }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( !(seen["B"] && seen["C"]) ) {
        for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
            print lines[lineNr]
        }
    }
    delete seen
    numLines=0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
463;88;1;193187729;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188065;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188527;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188542;280062;CDC73;IS;C;0.0
71;35;2;27400461;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27400930;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27401162;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27403518;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27403545;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27404353;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27419156;145220;NRBP1;IS;B;0.0
```

Comment: Correct. For this example, that's the output I'd like to get.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative

keeps only the keys of the lines to be deleted, but scans the files twice.  Also, file doesn't need to be sorted.

```
$ awk -F';' '{k=$1 FS $2} 
     NR==FNR {if($8=="B") b[k]; 
              else if($8=="C") c[k]; 
              if(k in b && k in c) d[k]; 
              next}  
    !(k in d)' file{,}

463;88;1;193187729;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188065;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188527;280062;CDC73;IS;A;0.0
463;88;1;193188542;280062;CDC73;IS;C;0.0
71;35;2;27400461;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27400930;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27401162;145220;PPM1G;IS;A;0.0
71;35;2;27403518;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27403545;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27404353;145220;PPM1G;IS;B;0.0
71;35;2;27419156;145220;NRBP1;IS;B;0.0
```

with `gawk`s bitwise operations, can be further simplified to

```
$ awk -F';' 'BEGIN {c["B"]=1; c["C"]=2} 
                   {k=$1 FS $2} 
           NR==FNR {d[k]=or(d[k],c[$8]); next}  
           d[k]!=3' file{,}
```

`or` is an idempotent function updates the array if "B" or "C" are seen.  If both seen the value will be `3`, in the second round print everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, unless you run out of memory:

```
BEGIN { FS=";"; }
{
    keys[$1,$2] = 1;
    data[$1,$2,$8] = $0;
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        a = data[key,"A"];
        b = data[key,"B"];
        c = data[key,"C"];
        if (!(b && c)) {
            if (a) { print a; }
            if (b) { print b; }
            if (c) { print c; }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that all lines with the same key are consecutive, this should work:

```
BEGIN { FS=";"; }
$1";"$2 != key {
    if (!(data["B"] && data["C"])) {
        print key;
    }
    delete data;
    key = $1";"$2;
}
{
    data[$8] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second version seems to work fine. The lines with the same key are consecutive. This way I get a list with all the candidates I'm interested in. That saves a lot of work. Can I also use this principle to get a list of all the complete lines with the resulting keys?

Comment: Of course. Just save the lines in `data[$8]` and print that instead of the key. Much like my first example.

Comment: If the OP modifies your 1st script to print lines then their file will be scrambled into a random order by use of the `in` operator. Your 2nd script only appears to work because the final record in the sample input contains B and C - if it did not and so should be printed then you'd find it doesn't get printed. Whenever doing something in a `current != previous` block you need to duplicate that logic in the END section to ensure the last record in the input is handled the same as the rest. FWIW I always use a function to do that (see `prt()` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263638/1745001).